# Rails & Kaminari: pagination gives me duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, kaminari

I am using the gem [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) with AJAX. The AJAX part is working fine. However, when I say in my controller **.per(3)** it returns me every object times 3. So when I have 9 recipes, it returns me 27 recipes (making duplicates). I only get unique objects when I say **.per(1)**, but I don't want a new page for every single object.

Please help me with this issue. Thank you in advance.

**My controller:**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @recipes = Recipe.search(params[:search]).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(3)
    else
      @recipes = Recipe.order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(3)
    end
  end
end
```

**My view:**

```
<div class="container is-medium" id="product-recipe">
  <%= render @recipes %>
</div>

<% if @recipes.present? %>
  <div class="apple_pagination" id="paginator">
    <%= paginate @recipes, :remote => true %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**index.js.erb:**

```
$('#product-recipe').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@recipes) %>');
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@recipes, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. For the people who may come across the same problem in the future.

In my recipe partial I had @recipes.each do |recipe| ....
That was the problem, removing that line fixed the duplicate problem.